# How to Play video in nsthread ..!

Tags: iphone

i need to play videos in nsthread.

It's not playing, movie player initialized well, but not playing video. Please tell me how to play videos in nsthread.

Also when play audio in nsthread using mpmusicplayer, it stops when i start another process.

Comment: Is this a continuation of your previous question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1397236/playing-ipod-library-songs-in-audio-queues-not-with-mpmusicplayer-controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can only play video in the main thread (goes for ANY UI stuff)

Comment: thanks for answer.... sir i need to play audio and video at the same time but from different sources, i used this code to play video on main thread  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(checkthis:) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO]; , but problem is that when i play movie , it stops song which i want to play in the background of the video ..

Answer (score 0):

The movie player framework is a UI centric framework. Because of this it has to run on the main thread. All UI work must be performed on the main thread.

Comment: i need to play audio and video at the same time , so i can play audio easily but when i play video the audio stops , can you tell me how to call that method in main thread.