# Recording Video while playing a video on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, video-capture

i am trying to record a video from front camera of iPhone using AVFoundation class while user watches a video...with the help of WWDC 2010 samples i am able to record the video using front camera when the video is not playing but when i try to record it while user plays a video in MPMovieViewController the video does not get recorded..When i use MPMovieViewController does it starts on a different thread due to which i am not able to record the video in the background?? is playing the video in a UIWebview will be a better option??

Answer (score 0):

Try using NSThreads. You should find some info about them in tutorials.

Comment: Bad advise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407691/how-to-play-video-in-nsthread